# Access link of a directive in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, directive

is it possible to have access on  link or data of a directive in a service?

my service:

```
    myApp.service('myService', function () {
        this.analyze = function (data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if( data[i].x ==   ) //<--- here i want to compare data with data in directive
    }
   }
});
```

my directive:

```
myApp.directive('dateInfo', function ($interval) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    },
    //templateUrl: '123/Scripts/directives/html/dateInfo.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html('<div class="panel panel-primary">' +
                    '<div class="panel-heading">test</div>' +
                    '<div class="panel-body"></div></div>');

        $interval(function () {
            var rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

            x = rect.left;
            y = rect.top;
            w = rect.right - rect.left;
            h = rect.bottom - rect.top;

        }, 3000);
    }
   };
});
```

I want access to "element"

How is it possible?

thix in advance

Comment: Pass the element as paramter to service.

Comment: a controller already calls the service, i can´t call in the directive the service, it would make problems with the data

Comment: Use $rootScope for shared element between service and directive. The $rootScope is global object